# Multiple machine communication from Hydro to Groovy

Tags: ros, multiple, ros-groovy, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm currently running on Hydro and I was trying to set up a multiple machines network with my lab robot. However, the robot is running ROS Groovy, and what we found was that my computer running Hydro was able to receive information from the nodes running on the robot computers, but was unable to send the same information back to the robots.

On the robot computers, the nodes running on my Hydro computer would be detected through rostopic list, but nothing would actually be received (ran tests with rostopic echo/bw/hz and saw nothing in all three tests).

We've been following the network setup found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup). When we troubleshooted with netcat, we were able to see the text from my computer on the robot computer. It would have no issue when my teammate ran from his Groovy laptop with the robot computers.

So is there a compatibility issue when it comes to sending information through nodes from Hydro to Groovy?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107961/multiple-machine-communication-from-hydro-to-groovy/) by [jakemorris](https://answers.ros.org/users/8671/jakemorris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-12-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no general incompatibility between Groovy and Hydro. They can transparently exchange messages.

An exception is if the specific message definition has not been changed between both distributions. But this is only the case for a very small number of messages and obviously not the case in your scenario since one direction seems to work fine.

I guess one of your machines needs a different ROS_IP / ROS_HOSTNAME to make it work. It is likely that you would have the same issue when both computers would use the same distro.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3